# Using different dynamics for different staves of the same instrument in MuseScore

Tags: software, dynamics, musescore

I want to use different dynamics ( `p` and `ff` for treble and bass staff respectively) in Musescore 3.4.2 but always the last one I've entered has the effect and the former gets kind of discarded.

Is it possible in Mscore at all or perhaps I'm doing it wrong ?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the element inspector, with the dynamic markings selected, change the “dynamic” mode from “part” to “stave”.

[image]